# In ASP.NET Core 6, how do I add an object to a collection navigation property of another object and save the changes in the database?

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-core, one-to-many, razor-pages

I'm still relatively new to using .NET with one-to-many-relationships. I'm trying to build a simple school management web app. So far I only have two models, one for districts and one for schools.

```
public class District
{
    public int DistrictId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; } = string.Empty;
    public List<School> Schools { get; set; } = new List<School>();
}

public class School
{
    public int SchoolId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; } = string.Empty;
    public int DistrictId { get; set; }
}
```

I've scaffolded those into CRUD pages which is all working fine. My hang up is in the OnPostAsync() method of the School/Create pagemodel. I wrote some simple code to assign the correct DistrictId to the created school and then add the new school to it's district's list of schools.

```
public async Task<IActionResult> OnPostAsync()
    {
        var DistrictName = Request.Form["DistrictName"];

        if (!ModelState.IsValid || _context.School == null || School == null)
        {
            return Page();
        }

        foreach (District district in _context.District)
        {
            if (district.Name == DistrictName)
            {
                School.DistrictId = district.DistrictId;
                district.Schools.Add(School);
                break;
            }
        }

        _context.School.Add(School);
        await _context.SaveChangesAsync();

        return RedirectToPage("./Index");
    }
```

I set some breakpoints and stepped through the method and I can see that the school is getting added to the district's list correctly. However, SaveChangesAsync() doesn't actually seem to be saving it, because when I try to view the list on the District/Details page it's empty again. I did some reading on entity states and I still feel like that might be the issue, but I wasn't able to find a solution that would save the changes. Any help would be really appreciated!

Comment: Try to add "public District District {get;set;}" in your School class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to add below code in your School class.

```
public District District {get;set;}
```

result:

[image]

Add `Include(x=>x.Schools)` in your code like below:

```
District = await _context.District.Include(x=>x.Schools).FirstOrDefaultAsync(m => m.DistrictId == id);
```

in your cshtml:

```
<dt class="col-sm-2">
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.District.Schools)
        </dt>
       
            @foreach (var school in Model.District.Schools)
            {
            <dd class="col-sm-10"> @school.Name </dd>
        }
```

result:

[image]

Comment: So this works for me as well, but it still doesn't show up on my District/Details page. When I set breakpoints for the Schools/Create page, just as you've done, I can inspect and see that the schools are getting added to the district. However, they don't show on my District/Details page. When I inspect the District instance getting passed to that page in the OnGetAsync() method, it has exactly the same DistrictId and Name, but no schools are in it's list. It's like it's a separate instance, but I only have one row in my District table. [GIF](https://i.imgur.com/ibzJ0Ac.gifv)

Comment: In your District/Details page have you add some code for school?  In School/details you can see " <dd class="col-sm-10">
            @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.School.District.DistrictId)
        </dd>"  and  " School = await _context.School
                .Include(s => s.District).FirstOrDefaultAsync(m => m.SchoolId == id); "  Check  the difference of two page.

Comment: Yes. I have a foreach loop that should display each school in the district. @foreach(var school in Model.District.Schools)
        {
            <dd class="col-sm-10">
                @school.Name
            </dd>
        } On inspecting this and the get method from the pagemodel it shows no schools in the list though.

Comment: What is your district in your details.cshtml.cs?

Comment: public District District { get; set; } = default!; 

        public async Task<IActionResult> OnGetAsync(int? id)
        {
            if (id == null || _context.District == null)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }

            var district = await _context.District.FirstOrDefaultAsync(m => m.DistrictId == id);
            if (district == null)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }
            else 
            {
                District = district;
            }
            return Page();
        }
    }

Comment: When I inspect it there before it gets sent to the page it returns the correct DistrictId and Name, but the list is empty.

Comment: Please see my update.

Comment: This solved it. Thank you! For anyone who might see this in the future, I believe the problem was due to lazy loading. Microsoft has a good article on it here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/ef6/querying/related-data